# least square solution of : $(2,-3,-2)^T x = (3,7,1)^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

To find the least square solution of : $$(2,-3,-2)^T x = (3,7,1)^T$$ The system is of the form $Ax=b$, where $A = (2,-3,-2)^T$ and $b = (3,7,1)^T$. So the least square solution is given by $$\hat x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb = (17)^{-1}\times-17 = -1$$
Is the solution correct?

Comment: Why do you think it would not be correct?